# Is it possible to do this simple Haskell assignment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list-comprehension

I'm going through [this tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out) from learnyouahaskell.com and it shows how you can make a list of triangles with the following code

```
let triangles = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <- [1..10] ]
```

Apparently this produces a list of tuples (or is that triples?) of all the possible combinations of (x,y,z) where x, y and z are between 1-10.

I thought it would be fun to try and reproduce this in Javascript but I'm having no luck. Is there an elegant (yet readable) way of producing this in javascript using reduce/map etc..?

I'm looking for an array of arrays where each child array contains 3 numbers. I would post my code but I'm not even close to solving this so I don't think it would help.

Comment: Do you want a list comprehension or a concrete (possibly big) array ? Or maybe a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generators) ?

Comment: To be honest I am fairly new to these concepts but I think I am looking for list comprehension.

Comment: Javascript has a non-standard [Array Comprehension syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) but it comes with a warning that it's probably never going to make it into ECMAScript

Comment: This really isn't a "simple" assignment… you could do this in JS with a `concatMap`  funcion

Comment: Hey I went 10 minutes before the first close vote! Is there not a badge for that on stackoverflow?

Comment: If you're curious: tuple is the term used for a sequence of elements of any size. "pair", "triple", etc. refer to sequences of elements of a specific length.

Comment: I don't see any reason to close that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the nearest equivalent of list comprehension in today's JavaScript. Comprehensions are in stand-by for now in EcmaScript, we don't know if they'll be available soon. But we have [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generators). They're not as sexy but they might cover your need.

Here's what it could look like:

```
var triangles = (function*(){
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
      for (var k=0; k<10; k++){
          yield [i,j,k];
      }
    }
  }
})();


console.log(triangles.next().value); // [0, 0, 0]
console.log(triangles.next().value); // [0, 0, 1]
console.log(triangles.next().value); // [0, 0, 2]
```

As in Haskell you're not limited to finite lists.

You can iterate like this:

```
for (var t of triangles) console.log(t);
```

(of course, if your list is infinite, you'd better break at some point).

And if you need a concrete array (which kind of breaks the beauty of generators), then you can use `Array.from` as suggested by Bergi:

```
var triangleArray = Array.from(triangles);
```

Comment: Maybe `Array.from(function*(){ … }())`?

Comment: @Bergi To build a concrete array ?

Comment: Yes. Of course one could argue that the lazy Haskell list better corresponds to the generator you have :-)

Comment: I thought this was the main selling point of that construct. But I don't know how to write something as sexy as the Haskell version...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this the lazy way (a generator), you can use [@DenysSeguret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36333020/67579). If you want to produce a list of lists containing these numbers, you can do this as follows:

```
var triangles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            triangles.push([i,j,k]);
        }
    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/am7zcgzz/1/)

This being said since both Haskell and JavaScript are *Turing complete languages*, every program written in Haskell can be converted into a program written in JavaScript and vice versa.